# vb.net Entity Framework | leading, pad, trailing zeros

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, vb.net-2010

The software uses Entity Framework with SQL Server.

I've ran into some weird problem while creating a large scale software..

I used Maskedtextbox with the format: 00:00 and DateTimePicker, pulled out from the EF (SQL) the date time as date.

In the SQL DB the date time shows "#00/00/0000 00:00#" this is what i did:

```
   StartWork.Text = Can.DateStartWork
   Hour_Start_Work.Text = Can.DateStartWork.ToString.Substring(11, 5)
```

There is one particular PC that pull out the data with no leading, trailing or pad zeroes(0) (e.g: for the time: 10:00 I get 00:0_ the masked isnt full)

Any ideas?

Thanks 
Tom

Comment: If you just want the time in hh:mm format in a textbox, just use `Can.DateStartWork.ToString("hh:mm")`

Comment: thanks but i tried so many things and formats to do it.. the problem is just on this PC! :(